# Error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile while building GCC 10 with offloading OpenACC Support to Nvidia GPU

Tags: openacc, gcc10

I am trying to install GCC 10 for Nvidia PTX on Ubuntu 20.04 so that I can offload the openACC loads to Nvidia GPU.

I am following the steps given in this [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Offloading#For_Nvidia_PTX:)

1. Installing nvptx-tools

```
git clone https://github.com/MentorEmbedded/nvptx-tools.git
./configure
make -j  #Generates nvptx-none-as, nvptx-none-ld
make install DESTDIR=/install
```

Exported the PATH, `export PATH=/install/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

2. Cloned newlib-cygwin,
   `git clone git://sourceware.org/git/newlib-cygwin.git`
3. Download GCC 10 source files

```
wget https://ftpmirror.gnu.org/gcc/gcc-10.1.0/gcc-10.1.0.tar.xz
tar xf gcc-10.1.0.tar.xz
cd gcc-10.1.0
./contrib/download_prerequisites
```

4. Added Symbolic link fro newlib in gcc source folder
   `ln -s /home/newlib-cygwin/newlib newlib`
5. Then, I have done out of source build(recommended)

```
cd ..
mkdir build_gcc10 && cd build_gcc10
../gcc-10.1.0/configure --target=nvptx-none --enable-as-accelerator-for=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --with-build-time-tools=/install/usr/local/nvptx-none/bin --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-newlib-io-long-long
```

6. I have also export lib runtime path for gmp,mpfr,mpc
   `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

I am getting the below error

**Error:**

```
checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: in `/home/gcc-10.1.0/build/nvptx-none/libgcc':
configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details
make[1]: *** [Makefile:13187: configure-target-libgcc] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/gcc-10.1.0/build'
make: *** [Makefile:947: all] Error 2
```

When I check the /home/gcc-10.1.0/build/nvptx-none/libgcc/config.log file, the error is because of this

```
configure:3535: /home/build_gcc10/./gcc/xgcc -B/home/build_gcc10/./gcc/ -nostdinc -B/home/build_gcc10/nvptx-none/newlib/ -isystem /home/build_gcc10/nvptx-none/newlib/targ-include -isystem /home/gcc-10.1.0/newlib/libc/include -B/usr/local/nvptx-none/bin/ -B/usr/local/nvptx-none/lib/ -isystem /usr/local/nvptx-none/include -isystem /usr/local/nvptx-none/sys-include    -V >&5
xgcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-V'
xgcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3546: $? = 1
configure:3535: /home/build_gcc10/./gcc/xgcc -B/home/build_gcc10/./gcc/ -nostdinc -B/home/build_gcc10/nvptx-none/newlib/ -isystem /home/build_gcc10/nvptx-none/newlib/targ-include -isystem /home/gcc-10.1.0/newlib/libc/include -B/usr/local/nvptx-none/bin/ -B/usr/local/nvptx-none/lib/ -isystem /usr/local/nvptx-none/include -isystem /usr/local/nvptx-none/sys-include    -qversion >&5
xgcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
xgcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

Please suggest me on how to proceed.

Comment: Any update on this ? I have the same problem her with gcc 10.2.0.

I made sure that mpc, mpfr and gmp were installed and up to date.

Comment: Please state your version of CUDA.